# Реализация пунктов меню в border-radius

Tags: html, css, ui, menu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно реализовать подобное меню (+ аналогично выделяется текущий пункт меню, по ссылке которого мы перешли).

Comment: Что конкретно у вас вызывает трудности? Для того, чтобы сделать закругления сделайте класс с border-radius, который будет присваиваться активному пункту меню. Если у вас отдельные страницы, то этот класс на каждой странице присваивать пункту меню, а если single-page-application, то тогда написать скрипт на js.

Comment: Как сделать закругление правого угла пункту меню, который находится впереди пункта, на который наводится курсор?

Comment: Создайте еще два класса, один скругляет левый верхний угол, второй правый, и собственно также присваивайте его как и с класс для активного пункта, в чем загвоздка?

Comment: Не могу понять как это реализовать на конкретном примере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu .qwe').hover(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('left-border');
    $(this).next().toggleClass('right-border');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.qwe {
  background: coral;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

li:hover {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.left-border {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.right-border {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul style="display:flex; " class="menu">
    <li class="qwe" style="width: 100px">Item 1</li>
    <li class="qwe" style="width: 100px">Item 2</li>
    <li class="qwe" style="width: 100px">Item 3</li>
    <li class="qwe" style="width: 100px">Item 4</li>
    <li class="qwe" style="width: 100px">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Средствами `CSS` никак, нужен скрипт.

Один из вариантов:

```js
$('.one a').click(function(){
var _active = $(this).closest('ul');

_active.find('.active').removeClass('active');
_active.find('.active-prev').removeClass('active-prev');


$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
$(this).closest('li').prev('li').addClass('active-prev');
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .5s linear;
}

.one ul {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.one li {
  display: inline;
}

.one a {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}

.one a:hover {
  background: crimson;
}

.one li.active a{
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.one li.active + li a{
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0; 
}

.active-prev a{
   border-radius: 0 10px 0 0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="one">
  <ul>
    <li class='active-prev'><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```